# Same font style desktop and mobile

Tags: html

How can I fix the fontstyle, so that on all devices it appears with the same style/size?

Futhermore: On mobile devices, the email is underlined and blue. how can i remove this?

Thanks for your help!
Mathias

Comment: you are talking about CSS

Comment: Please make sure to make a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question!

Comment: Given there are different sized screens, with the same number of pixels on them, and that browsers have never implemented physical units (like `in`) correctly: You can't.